# "Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers." in hyperledger-composer

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Afer using *hyperledger-composer* for several months, now suddenly the following problem is happening:

Whenever I want to start a business network, using the command:

```
composer network start --networkName mynetwork --networkVersion 0.0.1 --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw
```

... I get (after waiting for an eternity) the following error message:

> Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid
>   responses from any peers. Response from attempted peer comms was an
>   error: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT Command failed

I uninstalled the whole *hyperledger-composer* development environment and then reinstalled everything. I still get the same error message.

Does anybody know what the hell is going on here?

P.S.: here's the result of running "`composer archive list -a mynetwork@0.0.1.bna`":

```
Listing Business Network Archive from mynetwork@0.0.1.bna
Identifier:mynetwork@0.0.1
Name:mynetwork
Version:0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I re-installed the developer environment again AND restarted my computer. Now it works again.